# what is the meaning of "model" in data model or model data in React?

Tags: reactjs

[Thinking in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html) has mentioned about 2 terms namely

- data *model*
- *model* data

My question is what is the meaning of `model` in this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model means the same for both,
The only place I see them mention like you say is here:

> There are two types of “model” data in React: props and state. It’s
> important to understand the distinction between the two;

I think they are speaking about how props or state model are handled.

Check this link out:

https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#what-is-the-difference-between-state-and-props

> props (short for “properties”) and state are both plain JavaScript
> objects. While both hold information that influences the output of
> render, they are different in one important way: props get passed to
> the component (similar to function parameters) whereas state is
> managed within the component (similar to variables declared within a
> function).

Also:

https://github.com/uberVU/react-guide/blob/master/props-vs-state.md

Edit:

**I would say you can "model data" with the existing "data models" which are props and state**

check: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#what-is-the-difference-between-state-and-props

> While both hold information that influences the output of render, they
> are different in one important way: props get passed to the component
> (similar to function parameters) whereas state is managed within the
> component (similar to variables declared within a function).

Comment: "Model means the same for both", what's the meaning of Model ? Kindly re-check question

Comment: It means to use (a system, procedure,a proposed structure, prototype, etc.) as an example to follow or imitate.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#what-is-the-difference-between-state-and-props

From react page about state and props:
props get passed to the component (similar to function parameters) whereas state is managed within the component (similar to variables declared within a function).

Comment: I would say you can "model data" with the existing "data models" which are props and state!  I think this clears things up , even to myself a little bit more no ?

Answer (score 0):

In the react docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html#step-3-identify-the-minimal-but-complete-representation-of-ui-state), they are referring to the JSON data model which our  API is returning and which in turn we are representing in our UI in distinct components.

If this data model is structured and neat (that is only the wanted data is returned by API in the right format for representing in the UI), in this case, all the five components in the UI are utilizing the JSON API returned datas without having to map through unwanted data and also the component hierarchy contains all data in a nicer way.